# Populating a DataGridView from a DropDownList in Visual Studios

Tags: c#, winforms

I've hit a wall and could not find any resources else where. Basically I'm making a Room Reservation program within VS. So far I've got everything working and does everything I need it to do except populating a DataGridView from a DropDownList. I wish I could post pictures but I don't have the points! Basically I have 6 floors in a room and they are all in the DropDownList. I made some database tables containing the rooms in each room (6 tables one for each room).

Once someone selects a floor from the DropDownList, they hit search and those rooms within that floor are displayed in the DataGridView.

```
public partial class FACULTY : Form
{
    public FACULTY()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FACULTY_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'roomInfoDataSet2.Table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.tableTableAdapter1.Fill(this.roomInfoDataSet2.Table);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'roomInfoDataSet1.Table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.roomInfoDataSet1.Table);


    }

    private void xButton5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Rooms.SelectedIndex = -1;
        Floor.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }

    private void xButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void xButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        EMERGENCY EM = new EMERGENCY();
        EM.Show();
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Rooms_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Rooms_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Rooms.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }

    private void xButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Here's a picture of the window for better clarification:

[image]

Comment: Visual Studio is an editor...the version of .Net being used would give a lot more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `comboBox event` for `SelectedIndexChanged` you should get the value from the `comboBox` then load the data from database.

To make things easier add a class model for `comboBox` to your project, like:

```
public class DropDownModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Use a populate method to connect information:

```
private void SetFloorsToDropDown()
{
    List<DropDownModel> floorList = new List<DropDownModel>();

    floorList.Add(new DropDownModel()
    {
        Id = 0,
        Name = "SELECT FLOOR",
    });

    floorList.Add(new DropDownModel()
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "1st Floor",
    });

    floorList.Add(new DropDownModel()
    {
        Id = 2,
        Name = "2nd Floor",
    });

    floorList.Add(new DropDownModel()
    {
        Id = 3,
        Name = "3rd Floor",
    });

    floorList.Add(new DropDownModel()
    {
        Id = 4,
        Name = "4th Floor",
    });

    floorList.Add(new DropDownModel()
    {
        Id = 5,
        Name = "5th Floor",
    });

    floorList.Add(new DropDownModel()
    {
        Id = 6,
        Name = "6th Floor",
    });

    Floor.DataSource = floorList;
    Floor.DisplayMember = "Name";
    Floor.ValueMember = "Id";
}
```

**Event SelectedIndexChanged And DataGridView Filled**

I've attached the event of room to `Floor comboBox`.

```
private void Floor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

    if (Floor.SelectedItem.ToString() != "SELECT FLOOR")
    {
        foreach (var item in roomInfoDataSet1.Table.Where(x => x.Room_Number.Substring(0,1) == Convert.ToString(Floor.SelectedValue)))
        {
            string[] row = new string[] { item.Room_Number, item.Equipment_Type, item.Availability, Convert.ToString(Floor.SelectedValue) };

            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
            dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Selected = true;
            dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

1. **Note:** This will add the rooms data selected by floor to `dataGridView1`, so if comboBox `Floor.SelectedValue == 1`, this
   will add the rooms from 100 to 199 to `datagridView1`. But this is
   not the better way, you should add a column named `FloorId` to your
   table and search by `FloorId`, this will guide you to better
   results.
2. **Note II:** The current method works by getting the first char from the Room
   Number and  checks if it's equal to `Floor.SelectedValue`. But this
   will lead you to error if there's a room number from another floor
   with number 10 or 1 or 1000, got it?
3. **Note III:** I've deleted the binding source from datagridview1 and add the columns manually.
4. **Note IV:** You only need one table for all rooms and floors.

**To Clarify, an example of a better way**

On the line where you do:

```
foreach (var item in roomInfoDataSet1.Table.Where(x => x.Room_Number.Substring(0,1) == Convert.ToString(Floor.SelectedValue)))
```

Change to:

```
foreach (var item in roomInfoDataSet1.Table.Where(x => x.FloorId == int.Parse(Floor.SelectedValue.toString())))
```

**Code Running**

[image: Faculty Form]

[This is a link learn how to work with GitHub](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.html)

**Full Code From Faculty**

```
using LOGINPAGE.Models; //It's a folder
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LOGINPAGE
{
    public partial class FACULTY : Form
    {
        public FACULTY()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SetFloorsToDropDown();
        }

        private void FACULTY_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'roomInfoDataSet2.Table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.tableTableAdapter1.Fill(this.roomInfoDataSet2.Table);
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'roomInfoDataSet1.Table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.roomInfoDataSet1.Table);


        }

        private void xButton5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Rooms.SelectedIndex = -1;
            Floor.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }

        private void xButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void xButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            EMERGENCY EM = new EMERGENCY();
            EM.Show();
        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Rooms_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Rooms.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }

        private void xButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Floor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

            if (Floor.SelectedItem.ToString() != "SELECT FLOOR")
            {
                foreach (var item in roomInfoDataSet1.Table.Where(x => x.Room_Number.Substring(0, 1) == Convert.ToString(Floor.SelectedValue)))
                {
                    string[] row = new string[] { item.Room_Number, item.Equipment_Type, item.Availability, Convert.ToString(Floor.SelectedValue) };

                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
                    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Selected = true;
                    dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
                }
            }
        }

        private void SetFloorsToDropDown()
        {
            List<DropDownModel> floorList = new List<DropDownModel>();

            floorList.Add(new DropDownModel()
            {
                Id = 0,
                Name = "SELECT FLOOR",
            });

            floorList.Add(new DropDownModel()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "1st Floor",
            });

            floorList.Add(new DropDownModel()
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "2nd Floor",
            });

            floorList.Add(new DropDownModel()
            {
                Id = 3,
                Name = "3rd Floor",
            });

            floorList.Add(new DropDownModel()
            {
                Id = 4,
                Name = "4th Floor",
            });

            floorList.Add(new DropDownModel()
            {
                Id = 5,
                Name = "5th Floor",
            });

            floorList.Add(new DropDownModel()
            {
                Id = 6,
                Name = "6th Floor",
            });

            Floor.DataSource = floorList;
            Floor.DisplayMember = "Name";
            Floor.ValueMember = "Id";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can't upload .exe files to Github. Here's the dropbox link [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eqvyszog8ug6ldo/LOGINPAGE.zip?dl=0)